# why here 'or' follows with an 'else', what kind of branches do they make?

Tags: eiffel

I saw a really confusing statement when I read OMOHUNDRO's article about balltree construction algorithms:

```
--...
if pq.empty or else 
btm.bvol <= pq.top.bvol then done:=true
--...
```

I don't know how could an 'else' follows 'or' and there is empty after the 'or'.
could someone reorganize it and explain the branches of this statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `and` and `or` operators in Eiffel are eager: they will evaluate both operands.

Meanwhile, `and then` and `or else` are the corresponding short-circuiting operators. They will cease evaluation as soon as the result of the boolean expression is known.

In the example given, if `pq.empty` is true, `btm.vol <= pq.top.bvol` will *not* be evaluated, since the result of the expression is already known to be true, regardless of the value of the second comparison.

Comment: In Eiffel the order of evaluation and eagerness of `or` and `and` is undefined: It may do the second, and skip the first. e.g. `if function_call() or true` will probably be optimised to not call the function.